# python xml - multiple child nodes to dataframe

Tags: python, xml

Hi Guys I have the following XML

```
<Batch>
<Date></Date>
<Customer>
<CustType>1</CustType>
<CustomerId>123</CustomerId>
<Address>1 abc st</Address>
<Letters>
<Letter>
<LetterId>123456</LetterId>
<LetterDate>1/1/2000</LetterDate>
</Letter>
<LetterId>98765</LetterId>
<Letter>
<LetterId>5675</LetterId>
<LetterDate>1/1/2010</LetterDate>
</Letter>
</Letters>
</Customer>
</Batch>
```

As you can see, each customer has multiple letters and I need to get all this in a data frame like below.

CustomerID | LetterId |
123                     123456
123                     5675

I have tried pythons element tree libary as follows.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ETree  
u = open(filename)  
doc = parse(u)  
    for item in doc.iterfind('Customer'):  
        dict1 = {}  
        dict1['address'] = item.findtext('address')

        list2.append(dict1)
```

But when I try to get each of the letters I can't join each letter back to the parent node data.

I can either get the customer data, or all the letters but not both.

I need to be able to get a duplicate record of each customer as per the number of letters

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually worked this out.

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.parse(filename)
root = doc.getroot()

list1 = []
for i in range(len(root.xpath('/Customer/Letters/Letter'))):
   dict1 = {}
   record = root.xpath('/Customer/Letters/Letter')[i]
   for ancestor in record.iterancestors('Customer'):
      dict1['LetterID'] = record.findtext('LetterID')
      dict1['CustomerID'] = ancestor.findtext('CustomerId')
      List1.append(dict1)
```

Hopefully this helps somebody else